# ActiveMQ reconnect after network outage takes 20 seconds

Tags: java, activemq-classic

SUBJ, reproduces every time. Is it a magic number configured somewhere?

Test setup:

1. Start a broker.
2. Start a JMS client with tight reconnect-on-failure loop pointing to a wrong port.
3. Start a TCP proxy to bridge broker port and the port the client is trying to connect to.
4. Wait 20 seconds - client connects.

Answer (score 0):

That is going to depend on a number of factors least of which is the configuration you have provided to the failover transport.  If you have things configured such that the client is doing a back off on reconnect attempts then that would explain the issue.  Also the TCP connect timeout can have an effect here as the client might stall waiting to figure out that the connect fails.  You need to debug and play around with configuration to determine what fits your needs best.